# payment via Magento API,

Tags: php, magento

I’m developing a process payment via Magento API, and having a problem:

I created a shopping cart, added/updated/deleted product, added shipping method, all were done via Magento API, they all worked well.

If I used payment method like CC Save (code: `ccsave`), Check / Money order (code: `checkmo`), I ccould create an order for that shopping cart.

But if I usee Paypal Pro for payment method, I got an error at step create order

> (api: cart.order): Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1008] Credit card number mismatch with credit card type.

And the data when I call api `cart.info`, it also did not have card number, here is the data returning in `cart.info`:

```
array(.... , ['payment'] => Array (25)| (| | ['payment_id'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['quote_id'] = String(3) "868"| | ['created_at'] = String(19) "2012-03-28 03:12:21"| | ['updated_at'] = String(19) "2012-03-28 03:12:21"| | ['method'] = String(13) "paypal_direct"| | ['cc_type'] = String(2) "VI"| | ['cc_number_enc'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cc_last4'] = String(4) "1663"| | ['cc_cid_enc'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cc_owner'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cc_exp_month'] = String(1) "6"| | ['cc_exp_year'] = String(4) "2012"| | ['cc_ss_owner'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cc_ss_start_month'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cc_ss_start_year'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cybersource_token'] = String(0) ""| | ['paypal_correlation_id'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['paypal_payer_id'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['paypal_payer_status'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['po_number'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['ideal_issuer_id'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['ideal_issuer_list'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['additional_information'] => Array (0)| | (| | )| | ['additional_data'] = NULL(0) NULL| | ['cc_ss_issue'] = NULL(0) NULL| ))
```

I used a valid credit card.

When I commented code which validated credit card, I got an error:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1008] PayPal gateway has rejected request. This transaction cannot be processed. Please enter a valid credit card number and type (#10527: Invalid Data). It seems credit card number was not passed to paypal api call.

So, please can anybody help me to find out this problem?

Thanks and Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Paypal transactions are handled by Paypals servers. You must write your code to send the user there to complete the transaction, then have Paypal redirect the user back to where your API inserts the order.

See this answer here for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7063/soap-order-inserting-how-do-you-stipulate-the-payment-method